# How to fix blowfish secret error in phpmyadmin

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

I upgraded phpMyAdmin from 4.6 to 4.8 now on i got error it says
The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).
I've search how to solve the problem it says that I only need to add this line of code on my blowfish_secret.inc.php so i added

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'GGlkGmgpsp]9_[b2lXr5*a$BV4XO1lm+guJU3k(p$9z^9';

then i restarted mysql and my apache2 ubuntu and clear the cache like everybody suggested. but the error is still there. is there any more way to solve this kind of problem on my phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

I had

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin');
```

in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php.

It should be:

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');
```

(forward slash added)

Comment: Godamn, thank you ! I was going crazy getting that error despite setting it everywhere